# Data frame tranformation to matrix with counts

Tags: r

I have a data file representing the presence of genes in respective strains like this:

|gene name|   strains|

|BCAL0113|  MS2140|

|BCAL0113|  VC9970|

|BCAL0113|  VC9872|

|BCAL0113|  VC9842|

|BCAL0113|  VC9789|

|BCAL0113|  VC9670|

|BCAL0113|  VC9612|

|BCAL0114|  VC9444|

|BCAL0114|  VC8412|

|BCAL0114|  VC8319|

|BCAL0114|  VC7880|

|BCAL0115|  VC7879|

|BCAL0115|  VC7723|

|BCAL0116|  VC7722|

|BCAL0116|  VC7718|

I want to create a matrix that shows gene_names as first column (column_names) and strains as first row (row_names) with counts as 1 or 0 for presence or absence respectively. i need matrix table like this:

```
     MS2140 VC9970  VC9872  VC9842  VC8319  VC7880  VC7879  VC7723
```

BCAL0113         1  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0

BCAL0114         0  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0

BCAL0115    0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0

BCAL0116    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1

I want to create a matrix of the presence or absence of genes in respective strains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m1 <- t(matrix(c('BCAL0113', 'MS2140', 'BCAL0113', 'VC9970', 'BCAL0113', 'VC9872', 'BCAL0113', 'VC9842', 'BCAL0113', 'VC9789', 'BCAL0113', 'VC9670', 'BCAL0113', 'VC9612', 'BCAL0114', 'VC9444', 'BCAL0114', 'VC8412', 'BCAL0114', 'VC8319', 'BCAL0114', 'VC7880', 'BCAL0115', 'VC7879', 'BCAL0115', 'VC7723', 'BCAL0116', 'VC7722', 'BCAL0116', 'VC7718'), nrow=2))
df <- as.data.frame(m1)
t1 <- table(df); t1
```

Comment: i have the table in excel format. Can i read the table from there and convert to a matrix?

Comment: i have 2columns and 74774 rows containing data for Every gene present in strains. there are mulitple genes for every strain. i tried using the code as suggested by @ivan866 but i am not getting the matrix. any other suggestions please.

Comment: @tanu this is how I read Excel files into R: install.packages(c('XLConnect', 'rJava'), dependencies = c('depends','imports')); require(XLConnect); wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create=FALSE, password=NULL); df2 = readWorksheet(wb, sheet=1, header=FALSE, rownames=NULL, colTypes=c('character', 'numeric', 'numeric'))

Comment: iused this code :> library(readxl)
> virgenes <- read_excel("E:/virgenes.xlsx", 
+     col_names = FALSE)
New names:
* `` -> `...1`
* `` -> `...2`
> View(virgenes)
> m1 <- t(matrix(data=virgenes, nrow=2))
> df <- as.data.frame(m1)
> t1 <- table(df)

Comment: can you please share the code for creating a matrix from a file imported in .xlsx format.

Comment: @tanu require(readxl); virgenes <- read_excel("d:/tmp/fname.xlsx", col_names = FALSE); t1 <- table(virgenes); t1